# How to add two numbers in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, operands

So I am working on a temperature converter which converts Celsius to Kelvin (not responsive), and I want to add the value of the Celsius input to 273 but it's considering it a string. `type="number`" isn't working so I had to write a seperate code for that. Any help? This is my code:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title> 
            Celsius to Kelvin converter 
        </title>
        <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">

        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-MrcW6ZMFYlzcLA8Nl+NtUVF0sA7MsXsP1UyJoMp4YLEuNSfAP+JcXn/tWtIaxVXM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        
        <style>
            * {
                margin: 0;
                padding: 0;
                box-sizing: border-box;
            }

            
            .converter {
                display: flex;
                flex-direction: row;
                width: 85%;
                position: fixed;
                left: 15%;
                top: 27%;
            }

            .forum {
                width: 30%;
                height: 70px;
                background: white;
                margin-right: 150px;
            }

            .heading {
                width: 85%;
                margin-left: 7.5%;
                text-align: center;
                position: fixed;
                top: 15%;
            }

        
        </style>
        <div class="heading bg-warning">
                <h3> Convert </h3>
            </div>
        <div class="converter">
            <div class="Celsius">
                <div class="input-group">
                        <span class="input-group-text">Celsius</span>
                        <textarea type="number" class="form-control forum celsii" aria-label="Celsius" onkeyup="checkInput(this)"></textarea>
                </div>
                    
            </div>
            <div class="kelvin">
                <div class="input-group overwrite">
                        <span class="input-group-text">Kelvin</span>
                        <textarea class="form-control forum kelvii" aria-label="Kelvin" disabled readonly></textarea>
            </div>
        </div>

        <script>
            const celsii = document.getElementsByClassName('celsii')[0];
            const kelvii = document.getElementsByClassName('kelvii')[0];

            celsii.onchange = () => {
                kelvii.value = celsii.value + 273;
            }

            function checkInput() {
            var invalidChars = /[^0-9]/gi
  if(invalidChars.test(celsii.value)) {
            celsii.value = celsii.value.replace(invalidChars,"");
            alert('Invalid character');
      }
}
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just replace following code

```
celsii.onchange = () => {
  kelvii.value = parseInt(celsii.value) + 273;
}
```

rest you have done good job as your are checking whether input is Number Or not
One more suggestion instead of triggering event on change you may trigger it after validating number so NaN will be o/p

Answer (score 1):

The value from `input` is of type string. Convert it to number before addition

```js
const celsii = document.getElementsByClassName('celsii')[0];
const kelvii = document.getElementsByClassName('kelvii')[0];

celsii.onchange = () => {
  const getInputVal = Number(celsii.value)
  kelvii.value = !isNaN(getInputVal) ? getInputVal + 273 : alert('Not a number');
}

function checkInput() {
  var invalidChars = /[^0-9]/gi
  if (invalidChars.test(celsii.value)) {
    celsii.value = celsii.value.replace(invalidChars, "");
    alert('Invalid character');
  }
}
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.converter {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  width: 85%;
  position: fixed;
  left: 15%;
  top: 27%;
}

.forum {
  width: 30%;
  height: 70px;
  background: white;
  margin-right: 150px;
}

.heading {
  width: 85%;
  margin-left: 7.5%;
  text-align: center;
  position: fixed;
  top: 15%;
}
```

```html
<div class="heading bg-warning">
  <h3> Convert </h3>
</div>
<div class="converter">
  <div class="Celsius">
    <div class="input-group">
      <span class="input-group-text">Celsius</span>
      <textarea type="number" class="form-control forum celsii" aria-label="Celsius" onkeyup="checkInput(this)"></textarea>
    </div>

  </div>
  <div class="kelvin">
    <div class="input-group overwrite">
      <span class="input-group-text">Kelvin</span>
      <textarea class="form-control forum kelvii" aria-label="Kelvin" disabled readonly></textarea>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a string and a number type, javascript will concatenate those values instead of adding them, you must convert the string to a number using `parseInt()` if you wish to add them as numbers.

Change the following line in your JS:
`kelvii.value = parseInt(celsii.value) + 273;`

```js
const celsii = document.getElementsByClassName('celsii')[0];
const kelvii = document.getElementsByClassName('kelvii')[0];

celsii.onchange = () => {
  kelvii.value = parseInt(celsii.value) + 273;
}

function checkInput() {
  var invalidChars = /[^0-9]/gi
  if (invalidChars.test(celsii.value)) {
    celsii.value = celsii.value.replace(invalidChars, "");
    alert('Invalid character');
  }
}
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.converter {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  width: 85%;
  position: fixed;
  left: 15%;
  top: 27%;
}

.forum {
  width: 30%;
  height: 70px;
  background: white;
  margin-right: 150px;
}

.heading {
  width: 85%;
  margin-left: 7.5%;
  text-align: center;
  position: fixed;
  top: 15%;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-MrcW6ZMFYlzcLA8Nl+NtUVF0sA7MsXsP1UyJoMp4YLEuNSfAP+JcXn/tWtIaxVXM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="heading bg-warning">
  <h3> Convert </h3>
</div>
<div class="converter">
  <div class="Celsius">
    <div class="input-group">
      <span class="input-group-text">Celsius</span>
      <textarea type="number" class="form-control forum celsii" aria-label="Celsius" onkeyup="checkInput(this)"></textarea>
    </div>

  </div>
  <div class="kelvin">
    <div class="input-group overwrite">
      <span class="input-group-text">Kelvin</span>
      <textarea class="form-control forum kelvii" aria-label="Kelvin" disabled readonly></textarea>
    </div>
  </div>
```